# Обфускатор на Си

Tags: c, обфускация

Возникла необходимость написать обфускатор , читал , что скриптовые языки подходят для этой задачи лучше всего,однако более менее я знаю только Си.Вопрос : как написать обфускатор на Си.С чего начать , гуглил - ничего дельного не нашел.
Есть ли какие-нибудь мануалы по написанию подобного ?

Comment: Зачем? Обфускацию применяют для скриптовых языков, потому, что там код передается как есть. А в Си есть компилятор

Comment: О чем вопрос вообще: как реализовать код самого обфускатора? Или как правильно обфускировать "чтобы никто не догадался"?

Comment: А вообще, вопрос мне кажется интересным. Он подводит к "как написать статический анализатор" :-)

Comment: @AnT,как написать , реализовать обфускатор

Comment: Даже для самой элементарной программы , по типу привет мир

Comment: От "элементарности" программы это никак не зависит, как и от "скриптованности" языка. Для начала: что такое `strtok()` и как его использовать ты знаешь?

Comment: @PinkTux,нет, но буду рад любым примером применения для обфускатора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первые обфускаторы возникли, когда появились первые СУБД-подобные системы - dBase и FoxBase. Это было в 80-е прошлого века. Зачем они были нужны? Дело в том, что на этих СУБД делалось огромное количество коммерческого ПО. Разработчики его продавали. А потом его крали. Легко! Тогда защита от незаконного копирования была только одна - какой-нибудь код активации и всё. И если в ЕХЕ-шнике было довольно не просто найти и отключить проверку этого кода, то в скриптовых языках типа dBase это легко мог сделать даже начинающий программист.

Вот тогда и придумали эти самые запутыватели (obfuscate). Идея заключалась в том, что бы сохраняя функциональность программы исказить исходный текст так, что его стало бы практически невозможно читать. Самые первые идеи:

1. Убрать все нормальные переводы строки и вставитьих там, где от них никакого толка
2. Убрать все пробелы и табуляции, где только можно.
3. Переименовать все идентификаторы в совершенно непроизносимые комбинации букв и цифр.
4. Переименовать все метки аналогично.
5. Удалить все комментарии

В более продвинутых системах использовались ещё макроопределения для замены ключевых слов языка и других лексем. Ну, по собственному опыту, скажу, что получалось довольно эффективно...

Ну а проделать всю эту работу можно легко с помощью любой системы для обработки текста. Например - awk (его синтаксис очень похож на С) или даже M4. Основная проблема - надо до обработки макропроцессором составить таблицу идентификаторов программы. Так что, скорее всего, Вам придётся делать обфускатор двухпроходной:

1. Составляем таблицу идентификаторов
2. Заменяем всё на всё корявое.

А писать обфускатор на С, это не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: В вопросе речь шла о языке Си, программы на котором в подавляющем большинстве случаев компилируют.. Если собирать программу на высоких уровнях оптимизации, то идентификаторов не будет вообще. Так что «корявые» идентификаторы не помешают пропустить исполняемый файл через дизассемблер и разобраться в логике его работы.

Comment: **пропустить исполняемый файл через дизассемблер" - Вы хоть раз видели листинг дизассемблера? Но, даже если бы это был вполне приличный листинг, всё равно его разбирать гораздо сложнее, чем исходный код на dBase.

Comment: `Вы хоть раз видели листинг дизассемблера` — понятное дело, что с его исходным видом никто не работает. Тот же IDA позволяет: заменять числа на константы или побитовые операции над ними, присваивать имена переменным и меткам (а методам вообще можно задавать прототипы с типами, именами и соглашением вызова), заменять смещения на имена полей структур, генерировать блок-схемы, создавать именованные регионы с кодом, которые можно сворачивать, чтобы не мозолили глаза. Причём часть этих операций дизассемблер проводит ещё на этапе первичного анализа сразу же после открытия в нём исполняемого файла.

Comment: Это, конечно, не все возможности, что я знаю, но для диззассемблирования той же `fire.dll` (движок процедурной анимации) из Unreal-а этого было достаточно. И это с учётом того, что у меня нет ни опыта, ни навыков в reverse engineering-е (библиотека была нужна не вся и экспортировала огромное количество относительно хорошо документированных методов).

Comment: **присваивать имена переменным** - Вы описываете то, как надо бороться с обфускатором. Но ведь вопрос TS был о том, как самому сделать обфускатор. Я предложил: сделать на базе awk. Синтаксис awk очень похож на С. У Вас есть лучшие рекомендаци ?

Comment: `Вы описываете то, как надо бороться с обфускатором` — я к тому, что необходимость стереть все мусорные символы и восстановить их примерные имена из логики работы программы не особо усложняет задачу (т. к. в ряде исполняемых файлов их и так нет).

Comment: **не особо усложняет задачу** - я изложил то, что лично я знаю про обфускаторы. Если у Вас есть более эффективные работы для этих чудо-программ - будет очень интересно о них узнать!

Comment: `Если у Вас есть более эффективные работы для этих чудо-программ - будет очень интересно о них узнать!` — да нет эффективных методов. Нагородить можно много всего (вплоть до виртуализации), только толку ноль — всё равно взламывают.

Comment: **в ряде исполняемых файлов их и так нет** - их нет в бинарных стрипованных файлах.  Обфускатыро применяются исключительно для исполнимых скриптовых файлах. В которых хранится ИСХОДНЫЙ код программы, а не скомпилированный.

Comment: `Обфускатыро применяются исключительно для исполнимых скриптовых файлах.` — тогда прошу прощения за недопонимание. Я руководствовался исключительно википедийным определением (*«Обфуска́ция ... — приведение исходного текста **или исполняемого кода программы** к виду, сохраняющему её функциональность, но затрудняющему анализ, понимание алгоритмов работы и модификацию при декомпиляции.»*)

Comment: **или исполняемого кода программы** - может быть здесь просто разночтение поняти1 исходный/исполняемый. Чем исходный файл на питоне отличается от исполняемого?! На шелле, на перле, на... Точно так же было и с исходными/исполняемыми файлами на dBase/FoxBase. А "запутывать" бинарник... Я этого не понимаю.

Comment: @Sergey запутать бинарный код можно - вставить мусорные инструкций, заменить одни инструкции на аналогичные, маскировать вызовы функций Win API. Антивирусы с радость положат такой бинарник в карантин, так, на всякий случай.